# IF statement with ranges

Tags: google-sheets

How do I make it so that if any number in the range `C6:D11` on PAGE is less than zero, output "Some words" and if not, output "Some other words"?

I tried using `=IF(PAGE!C6:D11 < 0, "Some words", "Some other words")`, but I that gave me an error saying "Range has no entry corresponding to this cell".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the `IF` function an array (range), while it only supports a single value.

Try

```
=IF(MIN(PAGE!C6:D11) < 0, "Some words", "Some other words")
```

The `MIN` function finds the minimum value in your range.